Problems with cookie handling
I don't know if anyone has had this problem before, but I can't find a solution.
The problem itself is that apparently my frontend does not handle cookies as I would like, since although my API responses send and save my cookies correctly, my frontend or my browser does not take them. I don't know what to do, does anyone have any idea what it could be?
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true

Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, Cookie
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 106
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 01 May 2024 16:35:44 GMT
Etag: W/"6a-vXX+icxRdYRS33u39raS3nPooTw"
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
Set-Cookie: jwt=-----------------------------------------------------------------------------;
Path=/;Expires=Wed, 01 May 2024 16:45:44 GMT

One more thing to add is that I am using angular and express for front and back respectively. oh and I'm going to remove the token xd
I changed the CORS policies of my backend, added the withCredentials header in my frontend but it seems to be nothing like that, since I checked in postmand and it sends cookies correctly.

Where/how are you confirming that these cookies are not being used for subsequent requests? Note that these never show up in document.cookies

@Evert  I've been using an angular dependency called ngx-cookie-service, but it doesn't appear anywhere, and it's not saved in the cookie storage section of the browser, neither in the back or front url.

That page will not be able to see these cookies because it only operates on cookies in the current origin, so this is expected.

@Evert , that's too bad, but it's weird because just yesterday I was testing if I saved the value of my cookie, if you don't mind, how could I send my cookie from the backend to the frontend to verify the sessions?

If you find that you need to manually read cookies, maybe a cookie is not the right mechanism for what you're trying to do. A good use-case for a cookie are cases where it's fine for them to be single-origin and HttpOnly. If you're doing auth-related stuff, take a look at OAuth2.
